# web Initialization is not working correctly?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js

I have built a contract and have deployed to rinkby test network. To get the Web 3 access when metamask is not available I have done something like this but it is not working as I expected.

This is how I did it.

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

let web3;

if(typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined' && window.web3 !== 'undefined'){

    //we are in the browser
    web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
}

else{
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        "mynewmonic",
        'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/key'
    );

    web3= new Web3(provider);
}

export default web3;
```

Can someone help me to make this workable?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get this snippet from? Because if you read the documentation [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#id4), the `Web3.providers.HttpProvider` takes one parameter which is the network. I think you mixed it up a little with truffle's `HDWalletProvider` which actually takes a mnemonic as well.

Comment: Also if the account is not unlocked you will have to sign every transaction manually before you send it, as described here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction